# Ubuntu 22.04 unable to launch applications

Tags: 22.04, taskbar, gnome-control-center

Have a new Ubuntu 22.04 system.  Unfortunately it appears it is all locked up and I cannot find nor execute 2 apps that I installed.  Also the Activities Bar is frozen.

I installed Chrome from the .deb file :
google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

However there is no icon for it.

I reinstalled the gnome-control-center, apparently successfully, however there is no icon for that either.

How can I fix the frozen Activities Bar, get Chrome up and add the icon for the gnome-control-center?

Installed Ubuntu 20.04 via DVD which I then upgraded to 22.04 online.

Thanks for any help!